# Вылетает из всех устройств при запуске кода Python, telethon

Tags: python, telethon

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем может быть проблема. Есть простой код:

```
from telethon import TelegramClient, events

api_id = 2*****9
api_hash = 'ee****************74'

client = TelegramClient("Resend", api_id, api_hash)

@client.on(events.NewMessage(chats=-10*********2))
async def normal_handler(event):
    await client.send_message(-10********3, event.message)

client.start()
client.run_until_disconnected()
```

После его запуска, я авторизуюсь, пишет что успешно зареган. И как только код отлавливает сообщение - из всех устройств у меня выходит из аккаунта(соответственно и код тоже перестает работать).

С таким я уже долго мучаюсь, начинал с самого сложного кода, и вылетало при запуске.
Уже дошел и до самого просто кода, и все равно вылетает из всех устройств.

Скажу сразу, лимиты на сообщения и т.д я не превышал. Мне уже кажется, что нужно менять номер телефона, либо менять api_id и api_hash.

Что вы скажете?

Comment: Нужно сохранять сессию, после создание клиента. Там вроде client.session.save()

Comment: А так, вы наверное много раз входили в аккаунт.

Comment: Да, многовато входил в аккаунт. И вот не знаю, что делать

Comment: У меня возникла такая же проблема. Менял api_id и api_hash и IP через секунду всё равно выбрасывает... У Вас не получилось решить проблему?

Comment: Юрий, если вы еще не решили проблему, то я скажу как я ее решил. При каждом создании сессии для кода, нужно еще добавлять название устройства и версию системы. К примеру 
read_client = Client("read_client", api_id=api_id, api_hash=api_hash, device_model="iPhone 55 Pro", system_version="IOS 100.1", phone_number="*******")

Comment: Такая же проблема. Но теперь вообще не могу войти ни с одного устройства в аккаунт(